# MySQL query slow because of ORDER BY with Stored Functions

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by, stored-functions

My query goes from 15 seconds to 0.05 seconds when I remove the ORDER BY in the following query:

*simplified version:*

```
SELECT field1, fiedl2, field 3,  
    FUNC1(1, 2) AS score1,  
    FUNC2(1, 2) AS score2,  
    FUNC3(1, 2) AS score3,  
    FUNC4(1, 2) AS score4  
FROM table  
WHERE field1 = 1  
ORDER BY (score1 * 1 + score2 * 2 + score3 * 2 + score4 * 4) DESC;
```

I have a couple of stored functions that calculate sub-scores. Except I have to order the result based on the total score. In the ORDER BY I use `* 2` to add some weight to the subscores to influence the total score.

I use MySQL 5.6.13

Has anybody has an idea how I can make the ORDER BY, but not slow it down?
Like is it possible to and store the `score#` fields and sum them up?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Ok I found something out. The `score#` is a reference to the stored function. The ORDER BY is sort method which makes a lot of comparisations on those reference. So the stored functions will be executed a lot of times. Is there a way to set the return value of a stored function into a static field?

Answer (score 1):

The difference in time is because MySql needs to create a sorted temp table and fill it with data. As your query is running much slower when using order by, the problem might be in disk where temp data is stored. You haven't mentioned how many rows you are returning from this query. You may also try manually perform the steps that MySql is probably doing, so create a temp table with primary key (order_by_result int, n int auto_increment) and insert into it your select results:

```
Insert into t(order_by_result, n, ...)
select (score1 * 1 + score2 * 2 + score3 * 2 + score4 * 4),null,...
```

and check hpw fast it runs - you may also check this way if the problem lies in your storage.

Comment: I'm sorting about 2000 rows and what to return the top 20 results.

Comment: So you are saying to create a temporary table like: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS (SELECT field1, .. FROM table)` and sort this?

Comment: Temporary Table is NOT the solution! :(

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your comment? What happened? Did the query run faster? Have you tried only filling the temporary table (with primary key set to auto increment only)? This way you could measure how much time the gathering data phase takes.

Comment: And one more note - I was saying that you need to create a temporary table WITH PRIMARY KEY set to the value of the order by clause and an autoincrement (the autoincrement only to make the value unique). This way when you run select against this temp table data in it is already sorted.

Comment: The query was the same, except I didn't use a primary key. I will try to make a temporary table with primary key tomorrow morning. I will let you know about the results.

Comment: Just tried it with a temp table with a primary key, but got the same result. Temp table takes about 10-15 seconds to create / insert and select is quick. I really think the problem is nested somewhere in the use of stored functions.

Comment: If I create a view from the `SELECT field1, .. FROM table`, it will take only 0.0037 to create. Except the SELECT over the view takes again up to 10 sec.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `total_score` column to the table, and define a trigger to update it automatically whenever a row is added or updated. Then index the column, and `ORDER BY total_score` should be fast.

Comment: It's a real-time algorithm between two tables. I inject values of one table into the functions.

Comment: in that case it's better to think into transforming this funcions into a join with this other table.

Comment: @RaulLuna How will that help with the ORDER BY?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to precalculate the values of the functions and store them in the database. This way, the problem of calculating the values of the function on the fly will be transformed into a very simple ordering query.

As lowleveldesing has said, this type of queries forces mysql to calculate the product `(score1 * 1 + score2 * 2 + score3 * 2 + score4 * 4)` for all the register before giving you any output.

Comment: That would be ideal, but not for this case. I need to do the algorithm real-time.