# SELECT on VIEW is slow

Tags: mysql, view, sql-order-by, stored-functions

I'm trying to optimize an algoritmic query by using a view. I created the view like:

*Simplified version:*

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = MERGE VIEW view_name AS (SELECT field1, fiedl2, field 3,  
    FUNC1(1, 2) AS score1,  
    FUNC2(1, 2) AS score2,  
    FUNC3(1, 2) AS score3,  
    FUNC4(1, 2) AS score4  
FROM table  
WHERE field1 = 1  
); # only 0.003 seconds - approximate 2000 records
```

But when I try to do a SELECT query like:

```
SELECT * FROM view_name  
ORDER BY (score1 * 1 + score2 * 2 + score3 * 2 + score4 * 4) DESC  
LIMIT 0,20; # 9 to 11 seconds
```

The query takes about 10 seconds to get up with the result.

I already tried a couple of other solutions, but nothing has succeeded, see:
[MySQL query slow because of ORDER BY with Stored Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638949/mysql-query-slow-because-of-order-by-with-stored-functions/19654668?noredirect=1#comment29212266_19654668)

If anyone has a clue, suggestion or an answer that would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: How long does it take to just `SELECT * FROM view_name`?

Comment: Also up to 9 a 10 seconds

Comment: Try to figure out one or a few functions that slows this down. Try to create test view with only one function then with another. May be you can do function work inline in the query without a func call...

Comment: It's not one particular function that is slow. If I execute the query that I at in the view without the ORDER BY it is superfast. But when I add an ORDER BY or add it in to a view en try to SELECT it here is gets very slow.